# Acceleration of a yo-yo problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

Just to clarify, I want to make sure I'm doing this problem correctly:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/0AAwl]

What I get most confused about is the signs. So defined the positive x-direction pointing towards the right and the positive y-direction pointing downwards. That means the positive z-axis points in the page.
That means that the torque is equal to $-bT$. Here's where I'm getting worried: can I just equate $ -bT=I\alpha$? Do I have to mess with signs or anything? Simplifying, I get $ -b^ 2 T=\dfrac{1}{2}mR^ 2 a$. I also have the equation [; mg-T=ma;]. Again, does it matter if I wrote $ T-mg=ma$ instead? Solving for the acceleration I get $ a=\dfrac{2b^ 2}{2b^ 2 - R^ 2}g $. I have a feeling I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Answer (score 0):

The moment of inertia should be $mr^2$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}mr^2$
because moment of inertia of each of the 2 disks is $\frac{1}{2}mr^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the equation should be mg-T=ma according to the sign conventions that you have considered in your approach.As you can see mg acts downward( along +ve y axis) and T is in the opposite direction. This will equate to the net force and give acceleration.

Secondly,$−b^2T=1/2MR^2a$ is definitely correct from the basic definition of torque( rxF where r is position vector of point of application). The moment of inertia is also correct as M is the total mass of the yo-yo.